# help with regular expression to capture everything in a line

Tags: ruby, regex

I am wondering if there is a specific regular expression I can write to retrieve any information that follows 'Log1:' at the beginning of the line. This is what I have tried so far:

```
^Log1: ([\w|\s]*)$
```

but this only works if there are words and spaces, I want it to be able to retrieve anything that follows.. except the new line character or characters that are not really used in writing.

> Log1: important stuff here
>   Log1: it can have (), [ ].

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Note that the "normal" meta characters loose their special powers inside character classes. So `[\w|\s]` matches a single character, one of: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, `'|'` or `\s` (white space char)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
^Log1: (.*)$
```

The `.` matches any character.

Comment: _any character_... except `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: Not necessarily... only in multiline matching mode. I don't know if it's available in Ruby, but even so the question is about matching a single line.

Comment: AFAIK, most regex implementations will not let `.` match `\r` and `\n` unless you specifically tell it to match them through certain options/flags (`(?m)` for Ruby and `(?s)` for most other languages). Does Ruby enable `(?m)` by default?

Comment: @Bart No, Ruby does not enable multi-line mode by default. Your clarifying comment was correct; @minitech's answer is inexact.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
s.split(/^Log1: */)[1]
```

This will return `nil` if there is no leading `Log1` and the rest of the line, otherwise. If the line has terminating characters you don't want:

```
s.split(/^Log1: */)[1].chomp
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to read all lines in your log file, or are there some that don't start with `Log1:`? If the former, I'd just do `line[7..-1]`.